# Text Blinker in EditText

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a new project in Xamarin Studio, and Dragged a `EditText` on to the screen (Main.axml).

But when I run it in the emulator, it doesn't show blinker which I expect it to do, like in any other form.

Is this a drawback of Xamarin? I searched over the internet for this since yesterday but didn't find anything relevant.

I have also tried adding:

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

However, that didn't change anything.

Here is what I see:

[image]

Comment: I think the blinker is of white color. Any method to change its color to black?

Comment: Try this : `android:textCursorDrawable="your_color"`

Comment: <style name="Theme.TextEdit" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:padding">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/default_textedit</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor_colour</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
  </style>